# кодировка страницы

Tags: кодировка, unicode

на странице есть кодовый символ, например &#160 как его правильно конвертировать и как это делает браузер? Т.е. если страница в utf-8 - это неразрывный пробел, если в koi8-r - это ═

Пробую:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=CP-1251');
echo '&#160';
```

и

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=KOI8-R');
echo '&#160';
```

поведение браузера идентично, может я что не так делаю? Поведение браузера кажется не логичным, он конвертирует символ не обращая внимания на кодировку страницы.

И ещё вопрос: unicode - это подразумевается UTF-8? например: charset=unicode

Comment: Ну да, &#код; задаёт номер символа именно в **юникоде**, а ни в каких не в koi8-r. 160 **всегда** будет неразрывным пробелом

Comment: Символа `&#128274;` в koi8-r вообще не существует, но написав его, вы всё равно увидите превосходный значок замка  потому что юникод. Браузер всегда перековертирует любой koi8-r в юникод и работает с юникодом

Comment: @andreymal в кои8 - это &#154 | 0x9A 0x00A0 # NO-BREAK SPACE

Comment: «unicode - это подразумевается UTF-8?» — нет, utf-8 — это всего лишь один из способов кодирования unicode-символов, а бывают ещё utf-16, utf-32 и даже utf-7

Comment: @andreymal я понимаю, что unicode - это не кодировка, но что значит charset=unicode? все подобные страницы нормально отображаются в UTF-8, может веб мастера utf-8 имеют ввиду, когда пишут unicode?

Comment: charset=unicode писать нельзя; если отображаются — значит просто повезло и браузеру удалось угадать настоящую кодировку. Если веб-мастера пишут charset=unicode, то это плохие необразованные и вообще не мастера

Comment: @andreymal да, согласен, но в 90% случаев на страницах битый html, тут либо проходить мимо, либо работать с тем, что есть